# Graph api field expansion

Tags: facebook-graph-api, field

I would like to use field expansion in my graph api queries and when fetching posts comments etc...

but I would like to get picture from the "from"-field, but I would also like to get the category field so I can know if it's page or user.

If I don't use field expansion I get the category, but not image. but using field expansion I get picture but not category.

e.g

/me/home?fields=from
returns {id: 1, name :"x", category : "y" }

but using it like this:
/me/home/?fields=from.fields(id, name, category, picture) returns null,
if i remove category it works ok.

So is there a way I can get the category + picture for that field, or is there another way to know if it is page or user?